# Angular: RxJs .switchMap() call to back-end - optimal structure?

Tags: angular, rxjs

**What would be the optimal structure to use in Angular 2+ component so as to utilize the power of rxjs switchMap() in a back-end call via a service?**

**Notes:**

- We have a nested component firing a custom "fetch" event (so `fromEvent(myBtn2.nativeElement, 'fetch').pipe(...);` is not firing, see comment (1), so we workaround it with `Subject`. If there's a way harness `fetch` with `fromEvent()`, we could spare the use of `Subject` )

Sample implementation in StackBlitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/zaggi-angular-switchmap-stackoverflow)

**app.component.html**

```
<app-inner #myBtn1 (fetch)="onFetch1($event)" [data]="data"></app-inner>
<app-inner #myBtn2 (fetch)="onFetch2($event)" [data]="data"></app-inner>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({...})
export class AppComponent implements {

  @ViewChild('myBtn2', { read: ElementRef }) myBtn2: ElementRef;

  public data = 0;

  private BTN = { GET: new Subject() };
  private subs = new Subscription();

  constructor (private _ds: DataService) {}

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.setBtnLogic();
  }

  public onFetch1(ev) {
    this.subs.add(
      this._ds.getData().subscribe(res => {
        this.data = res;
        console.log('<<<', res);        // <-- logs 10 times
      })
    );
  }

  public onFetch2(ev) {
    this.BTN.GET.next(ev);
  }

  public setBtnLogic(ev?) {

    // fromEvent(this.myBtn2.nativeElement, 'fetch')   // <-- (1) this is not working
    this.BTN.GET
    .pipe(
      switchMap(p => this._ds.getData()),
      tap(data => this.data = data),
      tap(res => console.log('<<< observable ', res)), // <-- logs only the last response 
    ).subscribe();
  }

   // unsubscribes in ngOnDestroy() ...
}
```

Comment: So you want `fromEvent(myBtn2.nativeElement, 'fetch')` to work?! Are you asking about anything else? What do you exaclty mean by `What would be the optimal structure to use in Angular 2+ component so as to utilize the power of rxjs switchMap() in a back-end call via a service?`

Comment: If you don't want the canceling affect of `switchMap` you should use `mergeMap` to log every response.

Comment: @frido, just the opposite - I need exactly the cancelling effect and I wonder what would be the most elegant way (i.e. shorter and more elegant if available) to the provided sample implementation

Comment: @frido, (1) how to hook the custom event with fromEvent() as it would make the provided sample shorter (the Subject won't be necessary in this case) and (2) optimal = shorter/more elegant/or just another opinion on the implementation. Thanks

Comment: In your example you're binding the value `$event` you get from `app-inner` to `data` of `app-inner`. That doesn't really make sense. Why would you want to get a value from a component just to give it straight back to the same component?

Comment: @fridoo, the focus is on how to do harness the custom event and approach to use A2+ swtichMap optimally, the code practical use is immaterial